# Make flexbox divs wrap content vertically

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to get three flex box divs placed next to each other in a row.

```
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row">
  <div style="flex:1; border: 1px solid #ccc;">1<br />A<br />B<br />C<br />D<br />E</div>
  <div style="flex:1; border: 1px solid #ccc;">2</div>
  <div style="flex:1; border: 1px solid #ccc;">3</div>
</div>
```

Here, I have not applied any height style to the child divs but they show up like
[image]

Notice that the div with content 2 and 3 have assumed the height of 1st division with content, 1ABCDE

**Fiddle of the above code**
https://jsfiddle.net/4oddowjw/4/

**I want it to look like this but I do not have the luxury to use height on these divs** 
[image]

I cannot specify the height. As in my application, height is dynamic and applied to children of these flex boxes.

**Is there a way to make these divs wrap their content vertically ?** 
I tried adding 'height: auto' to the divs but it did not work out
**Example with 'height: auto'** applied https://jsfiddle.net/4oddowjw/5/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4oddowjw/6/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add `align-items:flex-start;` to the container:

```css
.container {
  align-items:flex-start;
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: row; 
}
.item {
  flex:1; 
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1<br />A<br />B<br />C<br />D<br />E</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
</div>
```

Your updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4oddowjw/7/

**Explanation:**
The default alignment of the container items is `stretch`. All the items has the equals height. If you want to wrap the items by content you have to overwrite this default value on the container with `align-items:flex-start;`.
More information about flexbox you can find here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

The official W3C specification: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-flexbox-1/#align-items-property

Comment: Thanks that works, will mark the answer as complete. Can you put a link to explanation for future readers of this question ?